# fetch specific data from firebase for different users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two users that are trying to send data to each other. One user posts a task while the other is trying to complete a task.

The user who is trying to complete the task can successfully send all different types of enum data to the user who posted the job, but the user who accepted the user to complete the task can only send one notification.

A simple enum that I have created looks like,

```
   class userNotifications {

// MARK: - establish notificationTypes

enum NotificationType: Int, Printable {
    
    case swipe
    case accepted
    case inProgress
    case completed
    case pay
    case reported
    case something

    
    init(index: Int) {
        switch index {
        case 0: self = .swipe
        case 1: self = .accepted
        case 2: self = .inProgress
        case 3: self = .completed
        case 4: self = .pay
        case 5: self = .reported
        default: self = .swipe
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the code that I am using to retrieve the data from firebase is

```
func fetchNotifications() {
    guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    NOTIFICATIONS_REF.child(currentUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
        let notificationId = snapshot.key
        for (_, postingRawData) in dictionary {
            guard let postingDictionary = postingRawData as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { continue }
            guard let type = postingDictionary["type"] as? Int else { continue }
            guard let uid = (type == userNotifications.NotificationType.accepted.rawValue) ? postingDictionary["fromId"] as? String : postingDictionary["workerId"] as? String else { continue }
            Database.fetchUser(with: uid, completion: { (user) in
                if let postId = postingDictionary["fromId"] as? String {
                    Database.fetchPoster(with: postId, completion: {(poster) in
                        let notification = userNotifications(user: user, poster: poster, dictionary: postingDictionary)
                        self.notifications.append(notification)
                        self.handleSortNotification()
                    })
                } else {
                    let notification = userNotifications(user: user, dictionary: postingDictionary)
                    self.notifications.append(notification)
                    self.handleSortNotification()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the code above, I had to use the code

```
 guard let uid = (type == userNotifications.NotificationType.accepted.rawValue) ? postingDictionary["fromId"] as? String : postingDictionary["workerId"] as? String else { continue }
```

Without this line, The only user that was receiving the notifications was the user who posted the job. This user can receive case 0,2,3 and 5.

While the user who completed the task is supposed to receive the notifications 1 and 4.

without

```
 guard let uid = (type == userNotifications.NotificationType.accepted.rawValue) ? postingDictionary["fromId"] as? String : postingDictionary["workerId"] as? String else { continue }
```

The user who completed the task doesn't receive a notification at all. I understand else statements, but that won't work in this particular statement. Is there a way for me to receive both notificationType .accepted and .pay? Im not sure how to manipulate this line into receiving both. If I change the type == to .pay, it will still call the .accepted and only that. Both of these notification types save successfully into firebase. just not sure why they arent retrieving properly.

Comment: Do you actually mean Notifications? Or do you mean you're writing data to a Firebase node that's being observed by the other user(s)? Also, that code could use some formatting so it's readable. Lastly, what is the specific question? Can you update the question to make it more clear what's being asked?

Comment: @Jay I am having trouble receiving specific notification types from firebase

Comment: You're not using Notifications in your code; either [Firebase Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or [Apple Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) so it's hard to understand what's being asked. You've got something in your code called `userNotifications` but it's not clear what that is either. Can you update the question?

Comment: @Jay the userNotifications is the class the holds my notificationType enum. I deleted the notification tag from the question. What I am saying is that I can only retrieve every piece of data from firebase for a specific user. Say User A. They can retrieve all of their notifications from specific actions. However, User B only retrieves one notification when they should be retrieving two. The notifications I am referencing is similar to Instagrams notification page that lets you track who followed or liked your photo. Is this more clear?

Comment: @Jay I have updated the enum in the top of my question to show that it is inside of the userNotifications class.

Comment: I would avoid using the word 'notifications' because that's not what you're doing and that's not what they are (see the links in my comment above. Also, when pasting code, formatting it critical as it was totally unreadable. I formatted it for you but please do that going forward.

Comment: I am not sure what the expectation is here - that Firebase code reads data once and only once using `.observeSingleEvent`. Meaning that if something changes your app won't know about it so it's not clear how the other user would know about those changes.

Comment: @Jay user has the ability to drag the tableView down to which refreshes the screen. the same fetchNotifications() is called for both users however it only works successfully for one. The line that I mention twice is what is causing the user to only read one enum. is there a way you think would fix this?

Comment: Well, TBH, that approach is not going to work well. You should be leveraging Firebase to let the other user know something has changed and not relying on resizing a tableView. It's also going to drive up costs for no reason - resizing should not re-load all of the data from Firebase. There are a number of issues in the code itself - silently failing when objects are nil for example. You need to do some further troubleshooting to ensure you're actually *writing* the data you want read and then when reading it, stepping through the code until you spot something that isn't right.